# Can I pull month and year from a date in a text string?

Tags: 2010, column, string

I had two calculated columns "Month" and "Year" that displayed forms grouped by these columns. They were calculated from the last modified column. 
Using `=TEXT(Modified,"yyyy")` and 
`=TEXT(Modified,"mmmm")` which worked fine until I relinked everything it now the modified dates are all the same.

Every time a form is submitted it has the date at the end of the "Title" string.
They will never have the exact same character length but the date is always at the end. Here are some examples:

- Daily Report_ Aaron Stinson - Weatherford - 2015-03-11
- Daily Report_ Andrew Beck - Minot - 2015-02-03

Is there a way to use a formula to pull the **month** and **year** out of the "**Title**" string?

I've been playing with LEFT, RIGHT, and LEN trying to figure this out but having no luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below formula

```
=RIGHT(Title, 2) 

=LEFT(RIGHT(Title,10), 4)
```

First formula will give `03` from `Daily Report_ Andrew Beck - Minot - 2015-02-03`

Second formula will give `2015` from `Daily Report_ Andrew Beck - Minot - 2015-02-03`

If you want day also then use below formula

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(Title,5), 2)
```

Comment: Thank you, it set me on the right track to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it wants to also pull the .xml file extension at the end. So I just had to adjust the character positions.

This is what I used for the month

```
=TEXT(LEFT(RIGHT(Title,14),10),"mmmm")
```

This is what I used for the year.

```
=TEXT(LEFT(RIGHT(Title,14),10),"yyyy")
```